# WinForms data binding without properties

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

In WinForms, is it possible to databind without using properties?

I've got a class that has some properties that I can databind to, however it also has some user defined custom fields that are only available at runtime. e.g.:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // I can databind controls to this
    public string Name { get; set; } // I can databind controls to this

    public object GetCustomFieldValue(string customFieldName);
    public void SetCustomFieldValue(string customFieldName, object value);
}
```

Is there any way to hook into the binding logic to call the GetCustomFieldValue and SetCustomFieldValue methods instead of getting/setting properties?

I've tried creating a custom binding class that inherits from Binding with the hope of overriding some of the methods such as ReadValue() and WriteValue() but they're not virtual so that looks like a dead end.

Is there any other approach I could try?

Comment: Can you show the code that does the actual binding? It's almost always "possible" using various strategies like data triggers, `IValueConverter` etc. Binding itself is pretty simple: You tell one control to listen for `PropertyChanged` events emanating from a class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  The trick - what often helps in scenarios like the one you describe - is that you can _manually_ raise the `PropertyChanged` event any time on any property and this will refresh the control. We don't have to wait around for a magically-bound property to do that necessarily.

Comment: It would probably depend on how you define "data binding". It is perfectly possible to use MVVM or MVP in winforms, but it is a bit more work since the framework is not designed for it in the same way as WPF. But what is the overall goal? some type of list with columns defined at runtime? Have you considered embedding a WPF control?

Comment: Thanks @IV. and JonasH - the type of binding I'm talking about is the built in data binding in WinForms (as produced by the designer) e.g.
`this.nameTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.itemBindingSource, "Name", true));`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I came up with in the end.

Create an interface for your custom fields:

```
public interface ICustomFields
{
    Dictionary<string, object> CustomFields { get; }
}
```

Make sure your classes that have custom fields implement the interface:

```
public class Item : ICustomFields
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> CustomFields { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}
```

Finally, I created an extension method to simplify adding the data bindings:

```
public static void AddCustomFieldBinding(this ControlBindingsCollection bindings, string controlPropertyName, object dataSource, string customFieldName)
{
    Binding binding = new Binding(controlPropertyName, dataSource, null);
    binding.Format += (o, c) => c.Value = ((ICustomFields)c.Value).CustomFields[customFieldName];

    binding.Parse += (o, c) =>
    {
        Binding b = (Binding)o;
        BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)b.DataSource;
        ICustomFields i = (ICustomFields)bs.Current;
        i.CustomFields[customFieldName] = c.Value;
    };

    bindings.Add(binding);
}
```

Then assuming you've got a form with a BindingSource and a TextBox control that you'll data bind to, you can use the above code like this in your form's Load event:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create an example Item with an additional custom field called "Notes"
    Item item = new Item() { Id = 1, Name = "Example item" };
    item.CustomFields["Notes"] = "Example notes";

    // Add the custom data binding using the extension method
    this.notesTextBox.DataBindings.AddCustomFieldBinding("Text", this.itemBindingSource, "Notes");

    this.itemBindingSource.DataSource = item;
}
```